# 97 Ford Ranger occasionally won't start

Tags: electrical, ford, starting, troubleshooting, ranger

It just recently began not starting every once in a while.  Not a click, nothing.  If I turn the key backwards the radio comes on and I can turn the lights on.  Then after a few tries it starts up and the radio/clock needs to be reset like the battery went dead.  The battery is maybe 2 years old.  Thoughts?

UPDATE:Now it won't start at all. still no noise.  When I turn the key backwards the radio comes on.  But if I turn the lights on (they don't come on) the radio shuts off.  When I turn the light switch off the radio comes back on.   If I hit the break the radio shuts off.

I looked at the battery and it looks like one of the connections is covered with white corrosion.  I hope it's just the battery.

Comment: I suggest you test your battery. Most parts stores will do it for free. You can also test it yourself if you have a multi-meter handy.

Comment: Thanks MooseLucifer.  I'll try that.  It just seems weird since the battery is only 2 years old.  Could it be a loose connection?